# How to check is context current running activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on my first Android app and I have one issue I cannot sorted. I checked out stack overflow but I cannot find the solution.

I have a menu which show 4 different Activities when menu item is selected.
I also have a class which manage the menu:

```
public class TabMenuManager {

    final Context context;

    public TabMenuManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean handleTabMenuAction(int item) {
        Log.d("Toolstrea", "TAB MENU HANDLED: " + item);

        switch (item) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                handleHomeAction();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_reorder:
                handleReOrderAction();
                return true;
             //.....
        }
        private void handleReOrderAction() {
            if (this.context.getApplicationContext() instanceof ReOrderActivity) {
                Log.d("Toolstream", "REORDER CLASSES THE SAME");
                Intent reOrderIntent = new Intent(this.context, ReOrderActivity.class);
                reOrderIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                this.context.startActivity(reOrderIntent);
            }
            else
                Log.d("Toolstream", "REORDER CLASSES NOT THE SAME");
           }
       private void handleHomeAction() {
           // Simmilar as one above
       }
    }
```

In all activities I show the menu I just call:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        TabMenuManager tmm = new TabMenuManager(getApplicationContext());
        boolean success = tmm.handleTabMenuAction(item.getItemId());
        if (!success) {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return success;
}
```

This class just simple show activity but I want to make sure it won't present the same activity as current one.
In this example I use:

```
this.context.getApplicationContext() instance of ReOrderActivity
```

But I also tried

```
this.context.getClass() == HomeActivity.class
```

It always log that the activity are different.
It cause the problem that if I'm in HomeActivity I can press Home in my menu and another instance of HomeActivity will be added on the stack and so on.

How can I make sure I present just one instance of the activity?
Is there a better way I doing that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Application context is always an in stance of Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `this.context.getApplicationContext() instance of ReOrderActivity` can never be true. You should change it to: `this.context instance of ReOrderActivity`

You also need to change how you create your TabMenuManager in onOptionsItemSelected. Change it to: `TabMenuManager tmm = new TabMenuManager(this);`

Comment: I tried like that and it shows REORDER CLASSES NOT THE SAME.

Comment: You also need to change how you create your TabMenuManager -- see my latest edit.

Comment: Yes you right I was passing getApplicationContext() to the constructor but now I changed it to this and it works. Update your answer so I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question. I have logoff button in my Activity and once user press it I call finish(); in my activity. How can I call this method from my TabMenuManager class?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. One way would be something like this: if (context instanceof Activity) { Activity activity = (Activity)context; activity.finish(); } You could also make your Activity class implement an interface and have your TabMenuManager class use the interface to finish() the activity.